# Как перекодировать строку в windows-1251 в Perl?

Tags: кодировка, строки, perl

Код:

```
my $str = "Привет мир";
```

Нужно закодировать строку в `windows-1251`, а потом пропустить через `uri_escape`, чтобы в итоге получить строку вида:

> `%CF%F0%E8%E2%E5%F2+%EC%E8%F0`

Примерно так:

[image]

Бьюсь над проблемой второй день, прочитал про кодировки в Perl, но ничего не помогает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. модуль Encode или Text::Iconv
2. модуль URI::Escape

Comment: Я знаю о существовании этих модулей. Проблема в том, что я не понимаю, как ими воспользоваться.

Comment: 1) Еncode::еncode('cр1251', Еncode::decode(твоя кодировка, твоя строка))
2) http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/URI-1.60/URI/Escape.pm#SYNOPSIS